# If I feel energetic, I play basketball or go boxing - how to illustrate it using an Euler diagram?

Tags: logic

A:

> Me Playing basketball and me going boxing are disjoint events.

B:

> If I feel energetic, I play basketball or go boxing.

How do we draw an Euler diagram if both A and B are true?

Can I draw it like my example 1 to illustrate it?

**Example 1:**
[image]

Comment: It is not very useful to draw them separately, the point is to collect the information on a single diagram so you can draw inferences from it at a glance. Draw basketball and boxing as intersecting circles (since no relation between them is specified), and then draw energetic as an oval stretching over all three regions within those circles (assuming "or" is inclusive).

Comment: Sorry, I am confused. If they have no relation, why do you suggest drawing them as intersecting circles? Wouldn't that mean they are related (some boxing events are basketball playing events)?

Comment: You could do both when you are energetic, or not, by convention any of the regions can be empty. On the other hand, if you draw them without overlap (or shade the overlap) you are *asserting* no overlap, you *never* do both. Your premise is an implication with no existential import. It could be that you are never energetic, never box and never basket, it can all be empty. The implication is still true.

Comment: Yes, I drew them without overlap as shown in my example 1 because I never do both at the same time and if I feel energetic, I do either one of them. So, does using an Euler diagram like my example 1 convey my idea clearly? And I don't think you can say some regions are empty because that is what Venn diagrams do. From my understanding, a region in an Euler diagram implies there are elements in it.

Comment: If your convention is that drawn regions mean existence of things in them then you cannot draw implications at all. They do not assert that any region is non-empty. Yours says "*if* something is this then it is also that", *not* that there *is* anything anywhere. Also, if you intend boxing and basketing to be incompatible you may want to phrase it as "I either box or basket, not both" because by convention simple "or" is inclusive. That you can draw as in causative's answer, with box and basket having a common boundary and energetic oval stretching on both sides of it, to avoid splitting it.

Comment: Sorry, I have a hard time understanding where you said a region can be empty. My Euler diagram means "if energetic is true, then either boxing or basketball." The two green circles mean the hypothesis "feeling energetic is true" exists, and it lies in boxing and basketball regions, which are the conclusions. If you make those two circles empty, wouldn't the diagram become "if null, then either basketball or boxing? This is not an Euler representation of my premises. I know in reality, feeling energetic can be non-existent, but that is not related to drawing a diagram, is it?

Comment: The point is that you do not know whether they are empty or not from the implication. "If false, then either basketball or boxing" is a valid implication. If you want to assume that energetic happens the phrasing should be "Sometimes I feel energetic, and if I feel energetic then I play basketball or go boxing, but not both". You'll need some device for indicating which regions are known to be non-empty, people put dots into them sometimes.

Comment: Ok, now I see it. Let's take causative's diagram for example. If the regions are all non-empty, then the diagram represents my premises. If the regions are all empty, then the diagram still represents my premises (because my premises will be vacuously true). So there is more than one way to draw an Euler representation of my premises. And to specify the regions are not empty, I can put dots in them. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, more or less. On the convention that regions are non-empty you need multiple diagrams to represent different cases of the original implication. On the convention that regions can be both empty or non-empty a single diagram is enough. Introducing dots then gives you additional flexibility in representing premises on a single diagram. But even with that there are sets of premises that will require multiple diagrams to be represented. For example, "I box or I basket" does not tell you which region to place the dot into, so you'll need to list cases.

Comment: @Conifold Thank you for your explanation. To make sure, on the convention that regions are non-empty, the reason I need multiple Euler diagrams to represent the premise where A and B are both true is because the diagrams have to visualize its implications (A: boxing and basketball are disjoint and B: where "if p then q" is true on the truth table). And on the convention that regions can be empty and non-empty, I can define the region's emptyness to represent the "trues" on the truth table so one diagram is enough like causative's answer is enough. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Sorry, I do not follow most of it. The way I see the reason is much simpler, you do not know what is or is not empty from an implication so have to draw every case. And in the second part empty region represents a blank in a truth table, not true or false. When you know nothing is there (false) you shade it or erase it, when you know something is (true) you place a dot inside.

Comment: Sorry for asking so many questions. Let me explain myself again. You mean I have to show the "True" and "false" parts of the truth table of my premise B (for example, if T, then T xor T => "false". if T then T xor F=> "true") and show also the disjoint relation of boxing and basketball. In short, on causative's diagram, I can put dots in a region to mean it is T and use shade to mean a region is F to achieve that. Then, I will have 8 Euler diagrams (because of three variables) with the same shape with different shade and dots regions. Am I right?

Comment: Which convention are you using? If drawn region means existence you do not use dots and shading, it is either drawn or not. And if drawn region means blank/agnostic then you do not need 8 diagrams. The point is to compress several lines of the truth table into a single diagram, as few of them altogether as possible. Just one suffices in this case.

Comment: I found a resource that explains how to draw an Euler for an If-then statement （http://www2.edc.org/makingmath/mathtools/conditional/conditional.asp). I think it is useful. However, it does not involve shade or anything about existential import.

Comment: When you are dealing only with conditionals there is no need to focus on existence, one can implicitly assume no existential import as I did. But when you want to represent existence and combine conditional and existential claims, things get more complicated. See e.g. [SEP, Euler Diagrams](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/diagrams/#EulDia) for discussion:"*representation of existential statements not only obscures the visual clarity of Euler Circles but also raises serious interpretational problems for the system*". Dots (Euler used *) and shading are devices to get around it.

Answer (score 2):

```
   ┌───────────────────┐
   │ I play basketball │
   │ ┌ . . . . . ┐     │
   │ . I feel    .     │
   ├─.───────────.─────┤
   │ . energetic .     │
   │ └ . . . . . ┘     │
   │ I go boxing       │
   └───────────────────┘
```

Comment: Is this diagram equivalent to my Example 1, where circles are drawn separately?

Comment: @vincentlin well, kind of, if you treat the two separately drawn "I feel energetic" circles as part of a single region.

Comment: Ok, now I see it. I can treat the central "I feel energetic" circle as two separate parts within the "I play basketball" region and the "I go boxing" region.